# Python removing duplicates.

Tags: python, csv, zip

I'm trying to get my code to remove duplicate inplace for a .csv file. Which can be found http://www.sharecsv.com/s/29ae855f20472de54b12fa66bbe3cbb9/DBA.csv

I got a suggestion on what to do and ended up with code looking like this:

```
def deleteDuplicate():
    seen = set()
    dupeCount = 0
    counter = 0
    with FileInput('DBA.csv', inplace=1) as f:
        f, f_orig = tee(f)
        for row, line in zip(csv.reader(f), f_orig):
            if row[2] in seen:
                dupeCount+=1
                continue
            seen.add(row[2])
            counter+=1
            print(line, end='')
        print(counter)
        print("Removed {} Duplicates".format(dupeCount))
```

The above code works perfect for removing duplicates on a smaller test scale like:

```
null,first,second,third
zero,one,two,three
null,first,second,third
nul,un,deux,trois
0,"1,one",2,3
```

When i run it on my larger .csv file it removes the duplicates perfectly fine, but ends up removing additionally 4 rows. The 4 rows removed doesn't get tracked in my dupeCount so they are not supposed to trigger my if statement.

I must admit that I'm not quite sure what the usage of tee() from itertools is used for and why it's beneficial.

My 2 questions are:
Why does deleteDuplicate() remove 4 rows in the larger .csv file and why is tee() and zip used?

Comment: I've never seen a tee function before. The `pandas` module has a `drop_duplicates` method that does exactly what you're doing here. Consider using that instead; no point in re-inventing the wheel. Documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: Assuming you haven't already seen this, here is the docs for `itertools.tee()` https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee

Comment: I have read the docs and understand both zip() and tee(). I just don't understand the benefit of having it here.

Comment: I dont think there is an issue with the function. The csv file you posted has 2036 lines (\n) but the csv module reads the first data row with a quoted string (" \n\n\n") in the last cell as designed. So you end up with 2032 rows.

Comment: @corn3lius I am not sure what you mean? When I run it, it removes 4 actual unique rows and it doesn't track it in the dupeCount variable that is later printed out. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the first rows of the data, the description has newlines in it '\n' (as well as commas) so we have 7 "lines" of data

```
Date,Price DKK,URL,Description
19/5,1 kr.,http://www.dba.dk/8660-vegavej-1-14/id-102010171/,"8660, Vegavej 1-14, hel�rsgrund, Boligprojekt s�lges 1-14 boliger
R�kkehusene ligger ud til et stort smukt fredet omr�de. Alle boliger har private sydvendte haver, som ligger direkte ud til et f�lles omr�de. Der er altan, hvorfra der er udsigt over det facinerende og karakteristiske landskab med �l�b, heste, gravh�j.
Aktiv fritid og lokalmilj�.
Tebstrup er en lille landsby med 660 indbyggere. I byen er der skole, b�rnehave m.m
se"
19/5,1.599.000 kr.,http://www.dba.dk/7800-4-103-372-2013/id-93506363/,"7800 4, 103, 372, 2013, Fyrt�jet 8, 7656, 6130, 80000, Villa"
```

But if read it with csv (and excel) the newlines are encapsluated by the quotes so its only one cell on that row.

```
with open("output.csv") as f : 
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        print( row )  

['Date', 'Price DKK', 'URL', 'Description']
['19/5', '1 kr.', 'http://www.dba.dk/8660-vegavej-1-14/id-102010171/', '8660, Vegavej 1-14, hel\xef\xbf\xbdrsgrund, Boligprojekt s\xef\xbf\xbdlges 1-14 boliger\r\nR\xef\xbf\xbdkkehusene ligger ud til et stort smukt fredet omr\xef\xbf\xbdde. Alle boliger har private sydvendte haver, som ligger direkte ud til et f\xef\xbf\xbdlles omr\xef\xbf\xbdde. Der er altan, hvorfra der er udsigt over det facinerende og karakteristiske landskab med \xef\xbf\xbdl\xef\xbf\xbdb, heste, gravh\xef\xbf\xbdj.\r\nAktiv fritid og lokalmilj\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\nTebstrup er en lille landsby med 660 indbyggere. I byen er der skole, b\xef\xbf\xbdrnehave m.m\r\nse']
['19/5', '1.599.000 kr.', 'http://www.dba.dk/7800-4-103-372-2013/id-93506363/', '7800 4, 103, 372, 2013, Fyrt\xef\xbf\xbdjet 8, 7656, 6130, 80000, Villa']
```

lines of the file may not equal rows in the csv data.

**edit**

Additions to your test file to confirm what you may be seeing.

```
null,first,second,third
zero,one,two,"three
,four
five\r\n"
null,first,second,third
nul,un,deux,trois
0,"1,one",2,3
```

Comment: Thank you a ton. You highlighted the problem for me. I still don't understand how the first row made me lose my last 4 rows in the csv. But by removing the first row, it made the deletion of 4 stop.